# Excel VBA delete rows if Date smaller than

Tags: excel, vba, date, delete-row

I have the below code to delete rows if the date under Column "D" is smaller than 1 July 2020. When I make `StartString7 = 44013` (the value of 1/7/2020), this code works perfectly. If I replace `44013` with `Worksheets("NavigationPage").Range("E12").Value`, it does not work. I cannot simply use `44013` because I need to adjust this every day.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vG7kj.png)

The formula in "E12" is
VALUE(DATE(E10,E11,1))

While "E10" and "E11" are the year AND month for users to fill in manually. (as stated in the above picture)

This should be something wrong with the value got from "E12". But I have no idea how to amend it. Many thanks.

P.S. Ignore the worksheet name.

```
Sub DeleteBeforeDate()

Dim c7 As Range, DeleteRange7 As Range, DataRange7 As Range
Dim LR7 As Long 'last row
Dim StartString7 As String

'change sheet name as required
With Worksheets("InPayments")
    'find last row in range
    LR7 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

    'range you are searching
    Set DataRange7 = .Range("D2:D" & LR7)
End With

StartString7 = Worksheets("NavigationPage").Range("E12").Value
DataRange7.EntireRow.Hidden = False

For Each c7 In DataRange7.Cells
        If c7.Value < StartString7 Then
            If DeleteRange7 Is Nothing Then
                Set DeleteRange7 = c7
            Else
                Set DeleteRange7 = Union(DeleteRange7, c7)
            End If
        End If
    Next c7
    'delete all matched rows in one go
    If Not DeleteRange7 Is Nothing Then DeleteRange7.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Dim StartString7 As Long`?

Comment: Yes,  you are right @VBasic2008. Thanks.